# Pearson correlation coefficient: Gaussian data expected?

Tags: correlation, normality-assumption

The Pearson correlation coefficient is sometimes referred to as a parametric statistic. Does this parametric nature imply that it is actually only applicable to data drawn from Gaussian distributions?

Comment: Statistics are not "parametric" *per se.*  What, then, would be the context in which you see correlation coefficients referred to as "parametric statistics"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation is a simple metric, such as variance and mean. These metrics can be applied to any type of data, normal or not. Pearson's correlation can be described as either a Method of Moments estimator (in which case you would say there's no connection to a bivariate Gaussian) *or* as a maximum likelihood estimator for the correlation parameter for a bivariate Gaussian (which does imply bivariate Gaussian).

The implications of this is that **if** your data really comes from a bivariate Gaussian, then Pearson's correlation is an asymptotically optimal way to look for the correlation between two variables (i.e., it is the MLE). If your data is *not* bivariate Gaussian, you are still using a method that consistently estimates the *correlation* between two variables, but it's possible that these two variables may have non-linear dependencies that Pearson's correlation may have a hard time picking up.

If you believe that there is a monotonic but non-linear relation between two variables, then Spearman's Rho is commonly used. It's my somewhat limited understanding that [distance correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) can be used to look for non-monotonic dependencies, but to be honest I'm not super familiar with these methods at this time.